# How to hide all URL in Firefox status bar when mouseover to any links?

Tags: firefox, url, hyperlink, hide, statusbar

Anyone can give me the answer? TQ.

Comment: gud intended phishing..legal..

Answer (score 1):

Convert all anchors from `href` to `onClick` javascript.

Before implementation:

```
<a href="mylink.html">MyLink</a>
```

After implementation:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:document.location="mylink.html">MyLink</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

this looks pretty suspect, but:

make the href attribute of your links do nothing...

```
<a href="#">Link Text</a>
```

and use onclick handlers to change pages.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.location='http://newurl.com'>Link Text</a>
```

Comment: but i want to hide all links. all hosted links that cannot be insert the codes.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you want then.  Do you want to hide the links in other users' (that you don't control) Firefox windows, or just on computers you can control?

Comment: in mozilla, it can not be hide. also i cannot edit like above coz the links are hosted. so can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="href='mylink.html'">...your text link...</a>
```